# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've tried http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VKQwEo?editors=0010 from React's documentation it works fine.

I want to make a button using material-ui.
What is wrong with this code?

```
    import * as React from "react";   
    import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router";

    const FlatButton = require('material-ui/FlatButton');


    function Test(props){
    return(
    <div className="test">
    aaa
    <FlatButton label="Default" />
    </div>
    );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
    <Test

    />
    , document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Errors:

---

```
invariant.js:39 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Test

warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Test`
```

---

Comment: try `import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'` or `const FlatButton = require('material-ui/FlatButton').default`

Answer (score 1):

If u r using `material ui` component then u need to import `MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme` from `material-ui`, and wrap ur component by 
`MuiThemeProvider`, try this it will work:

```
import React from "react";   
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router";
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
const getMuiTheme = getMuiTheme({});

import FlatButton from 'material-ui';

 const App = (props) => {

    return (
         <FlatButton label='default'  />
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(
   <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

check `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/u7yvr564/

Comment: if i just copy/paste i get error `TS1141: String literal expected.` on line `import { RaisedButton, MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme, FlatButton } from `material-ui`;`

Comment: if i do it like that i get a lot of `error: cannot find` , but if i change import to const like this  `const MuiThemeProvider = require('material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider');
 const getMuiTheme = require('material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme').default;` i get `React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components)` and `invariant.js:39 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: reason is you used id = 'root', i used id = 'container', just use the id that u defined in html page.

Comment: i've seen that. still not working. it is still giving me the same error in chrome console from the previous  comment .

Comment: have u used the proper id ??

Comment: yes i did. just deleted all other code. from the render and inserted the one you provided plus my changes from the comment. import -> const...

Comment: have u included bundle.js script reference in html ?

Comment: it is included in using webpack (webpack.config.js)

Comment: but u have to give the reference in html file also, html body should be like this: `<body>
 <div id="app"/> 
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>`

Comment: yes i understand i have the fallowing line in my index.html if i look at it in browser console. but it is add automatically by webpack.